# Unable to start twilio project

Tags: node.js, twilio, npm-start, twilio-flex, twilio-cli

I have a twilio flex plugin project.  I normally start the project with `npm start` which is aliased to `UNBUNDLED_REACT=true twilio flex:plugins:start` within my `package.json` file.  However, today when I run `npm start`, I'm getting the following error:

```
 » Could not get credentials for profile "my_email@my_work.com".
 » To reconfigure the profile, run: twilio profiles:create`

Also logged to the console is a message that gives me a path to a log file.  Within that log file I see the following content:

`0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   '/usr/local/Cellar/node/14.11.0/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/usr/local/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'start'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.8
3 info using node@v14.11.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle twilio-flex-agent-dashboard@0.0.2~prestart: twilio-flex-agent-dashboard@0.0.2
6 info lifecycle twilio-flex-agent-dashboard@0.0.2~start: twilio-flex-agent-dashboard@0.0.2
7 verbose lifecycle twilio-flex-agent-dashboard@0.0.2~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle twilio-flex-agent-dashboard@0.0.2~start: PATH: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/Users/my_user/Desktop/twilio-flex-agent-dashboard/node_modules/.bin:/Users/my_user/kafka-stuff/bin:/usr/local/opt/postgresql@9.6/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin
9 verbose lifecycle twilio-flex-agent-dashboard@0.0.2~start: CWD: /Users/my_user/Desktop/twilio-flex-agent-dashboard
10 silly lifecycle twilio-flex-agent-dashboard@0.0.2~start: Args: [ '-c', 'UNBUNDLED_REACT=true twilio flex:plugins:start' ]
11 silly lifecycle twilio-flex-agent-dashboard@0.0.2~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle twilio-flex-agent-dashboard@0.0.2~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: twilio-flex-agent-dashboard@0.0.2 start: `UNBUNDLED_REACT=true twilio flex:plugins:start`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:314:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:314:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1047:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:287:5)
14 verbose pkgid twilio-flex-agent-dashboard@0.0.2
15 verbose cwd /Users/my_user/Desktop/twilio-flex-agent-dashboard
16 verbose Darwin 20.5.0
17 verbose argv "/usr/local/Cellar/node/14.11.0/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "start"
18 verbose node v14.11.0
19 verbose npm  v6.14.8
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error twilio-flex-agent-dashboard@0.0.2 start: `UNBUNDLED_REACT=true twilio flex:plugins:start`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the twilio-flex-agent-dashboard@0.0.2 start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

When I do what the original error message is suggesting (ie running `twilio profiles:create`, I get a success message.  However, I'm still unable to start the project.

So my question is, what has happened to my system where now I'm getting this error, and how do I fix it so I can start my project with `npm start` like I was doing previously?

Answer (score 1):

Alright, issue has been resolved,  My issue was that I was entering what I thought was the correct username when I ran `twilio profiles:create`, but really in fact, was the wrong username.  Entering the correct username has resolved this issue.